# Jest: test that an array contains none of these values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, jestjs, assertion

I want to verify that a given array doesn't contain any of a list of values. There is `expect.arrayContaining` but I don't get how it is supposed to be used for this.

See this example:

```js
expect(["1", "2", "3"]).not.toEqual(expect.arrayContaining(["3"])
```

This test fails which is the expected behavior. I want to verify that "3" is not included in the array. Everything fine.

However, now I have multiple values for which I want the test to fail if the array contains any of them.

```js
expect(["1", "2", "3"]).not.toEqual(expect.arrayContaining(["3", "4"])
```

This test does not fail even though I would expect it to fail because the array contains the "3".

What I could do is this:

```js
expect(["1", "2", "3"]).not.toEqual(expect.arrayContaining(["3"])
expect(["1", "2", "3"]).not.toEqual(expect.arrayContaining(["4"])
...
```

But having to repeat the whole expect line for every single value doesn't seem to be the right way. Especially when `arrayContaining` takes an array as argument while it looks like you can only pass it a single value to be useful.

I'm sure there are valid use-cases for this behavior but I'm asking how I can implement by use-case in a more concise way. Basically, I want the test to fail as soon as the array contains one or more values of the second array. Sort of a "blacklist".

Comment: For a single value you can use `.not.toContain`, for multiple values you'd need `jest-extended`'s [`.not.toIncludeAnyMembers`](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended#toincludeanymembersmembers).

Comment: The combinations you have tried do not make any sense. `expect.arrayContaining()` is meant to be used in a different context. You should use `expect(actual).not.toContain('3')`, `expect(actual).not.toContain('4')` and so on for each value expected to not be present in `actual`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of trying to get Jest to check whether your arrays intersect, I'd instead create a small function to check that and then apply an assertion on the result e.g.

```
const doArraysIntersect 
 = (array1, array2) => array1.some(item1 => array2.includes(item1))

expect(doArraysIntersect(["1", "2", "3"], ["3"])).toBe(true);
```

I would also recommend using positive logic (i.e. try and minimize the use of `not`) as I have done in my example, as negative logic (i.e. muliple instances of negative logic e.g. using shouldntHave and not in the same assertion) can be harder to reason with.

EDIT: To be clear, I quite like custom matchers when used appropriately. When sorting through somebody else's code to fix a bug, I don't want to have to pause at tests which use double negatives. Assertions should be simple and obvious :D

Answer (score 21):

Don't overthink the perfect matcher, just write your test and move on:

```
const shouldntHave = [4,5,6];
const subject = [1,2,3]

shouldntHave.map(m => expect(subject).not.toContain(m));
```

EDIT: To be clear, I despise custom matchers. I'm already sorting through somebody else's code to fix a bug, I don't want to have to dive deep into testing infrastructure as well. Assertions should be simple and obvious.